# How to Delete Database in Azure

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

When I delete my database in MS Azure,there occur an error of sync group or agents.
when i go to sync groups in azure ,there is no sync group.
Can anybody help?

[image: Failed to Delete DB]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that database was used as part of a replication using Azure SQL Data Sync and there are some remnants of that configuration on the database.

Please go to the on-premises computer that was part on the sync group and run the deprovision tool. Under the "C:\program files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Azure Data Sync" directory you should find an utility named deprovisionUtil.exe. That tool can be run with the /F switch to remove the DSS schema and objects installed by SQL Data Sync.

If you started a manual clean up already of the DSS objects created by SQL Data Sync, please run the script provided [here](https://github.com/vitomaz-msft/DataSyncMetadataCleanup) to remove the remnants left behind.

Let me know if after executing above procedure you can now delete your database.

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete objects from your database. You cannot delete the database because there are still sync groups or sync agents registered in the Azure backend. Only way you can unlock this database is to remove all the sync groups and sync agents. Deleting records from your table will break it completely and you will need to file a support request to have your sync account cleared in the backend.